# In ADV's "Class album: The Complete Azumanga Daioh" 5-disc box set, why are the episodes distributed 5-4-5-5-7?

Tags: anime-production, azumanga-daioh

This is just a small thing that I've been wondering about for a while now.

In ADV's 2005 release of "Class album: The Complete Azumanga Daioh", the episodes are distributed as follows:

- [1st disc](https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM364991&R=364991): 5 episodes (1-5)
- [2nd disc](https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM769351&R=769351): 4 episodes (6-9)
- [3rd disc](https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM708713&R=708713): 5 episodes (10-14)
- [4th disc](https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM734340&R=734340): 5 episodes (15-19)
- [5th disc](https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM120306&R=120306): 7 episodes (20-26)

This seems a bit odd. It looks like they crammed 7 episodes into the last disc when the second disc still had room. Normally, you'd expect a more even distribution such as 5-5-5-5-6. Is there a reason why it was distributed this way?

Comment: I didn't watched any of it but couldn't it be because of the "organization" of the main plot? Just speculating...

Comment: is there any special features on them like trailers, japanese promos, Textless OPs or EDs, etc? these do take up space on the disk aswell so could impact the number of episodes per disk

Comment: Considering that the DVD includes the dubbed version, it might be related to the file size due to the amount of the speech, which also possibly affect the overall quality.

Comment: I don't think there are any extra features of any kind (based on the reviews [here](https://www.dvdtalk.com/reviews/17957/azumanga-daioh-class-album/) and [here](https://www.amazon.ca/Azumanga-Daioh-Animation-Class-Complete/dp/B000ADKWNM)).

Audio takes up a lot less space than video, so I don't think it's related to the amount of speech.

I notice now that there was an earlier 6-disc box set that follows a similar pattern for the first four discs (see [here](https://www.myreviewer.com/DVD/109318/Azumanga-Daioh-Complete-Collection-6-Discs/109473/Review-by-Jitendar-Canth)). A clue, perhaps?